# Equivalent of disabling services in Windows to lessen CPU/RAM usage for OS X?

Tags: macos, performance

When it comes to the underside of things I know a lot more about Windows than Mac/OS X, so I'm not sure if OS X is even like this in this aspect but what I'm wanting to know is I used to very thoroughly disable system services in Windows for things I didn't need like network file sharing and quick user switching, just to name a couple, to make the computer run lighter.
It worked great on aging systems and I was wondering if there was an equivalent of such a thing for OS X that I could pick through and at my risk disable just to help my old Late 2006 iMac?

Answer (score 1):

OS X doesn't come with a bunch of unneeded services loaded in the background taking up resources. Most OSes are not as bloated as Windows. There really isn't anything to disable, unless you enabled something that you no longer need. OS X is pretty conservative with what it enables by default, and it often will enable things automatically as needed, and keep them disabled when not.